# Find Matrix T of a Linear Transformation $T: M_{2\times 2} \to P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Been staring at this practice problem and scribbling nonsense for quite a while now googled extensively and such but nothing triggered any spark of understanding.
All in all a helpful shove off the correct cliff would be appreciated.

Consider the linear transformation $T: M_{2\times 2} \to P_3$ given by

$$
T\left ( \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix} \right ) = (a + b + c) +(a - b - c)x + (a + d)x^2 + (b + c - d)x^3
 $$

(a) Find the matix of T with respect to the usual bases for $M_{2x2}$ and $P_3$

(b) Now consider the basis $B$ of $M_{2x2}$ given by

$$
B =\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\-1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$

and the basis of $C$ of $P_3$ given by 
$C =\left\{ 1+x+x^2, 1-x+x^3, x^2+x^3,x^2-x^3\right\}$

find the matrix $\left[T\right]_{C\leftarrow B}$

Comment: Do you know what the usual basis for $M_{22}$ and $P_3$ are?

Comment: No I don't unfortunately, its one of the things that's making it difficult for me to figure out where to start.

Comment: For the $2\times 2$ matrices, the standard basis would be
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0&0   \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
The standard basis for the polynomials is ${1, x, x^2, x^3}$. Do you understand why these two sets are a basis in each case? Do you know how to get the matrix for given these bases?

Comment: I think I understand why each is a basis, How to get the matrix for T given these each one alludes me though.

Comment: The matrices form a basis because given any $2\times 2 $ matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ c&d \end{pmatrix}
$$
you can write it as:
$$
a\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix} +c \begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\1&0 \end{pmatrix} +d \begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and similarly for the polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $2\times 2$ matrices, the standard basis would be
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0&0   \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

and for the polynomials the standard basis is $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$. Now you want to see what $T$ does to the standard basis of $M_{22}$ and write it in terms of the standard basis of $P_3$. Using the definition of $T$ we get that:

$$
\begin{split} T\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}&=1+x+x^2 \\ T\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix} &=1-x+x^3 \\ T\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\1&0 \end{pmatrix} &= 1-x+x^3 \\ T\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix} &=x^2-x^3 \end{split}
$$

Now in the standard basis of $P_3$, $1+x+x^2$ corresponds to the column vector:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Combining the column vectors for each of the basis matrices gives the matrix of $T$ in the standard basis:
$$
T=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1&0 \\ 1&-1&-1&0 \\ 1&0&0&1 \\0&1&1&-1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

It would be a good exercise for you to do part b). The process will be the same but you will need to write the polynomials you get in terms of the polynomials in the new basis. For example, in the new basis $C$, the polynomial $1+x+x^2$ now corresponds to the vector:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Okay Great that makes a lot more sense now, thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For part a), note that $T$ is determined by its effect on the basis vectors of $M_{22}$ so for instance

$T\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $=$\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

where the RHS is a column vector written in terms of the standard basis in $P_3$ i.e.$\ \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$ represents the vector $1(1)+1(x)+1(x^2)+0(x^3)=1+x+x^2$.

In part b) you are given dfferent bases for $M_{22}$  and $P_3$ but the idea is the same: find $T$ on the new basis vectors in $M_{22}$ and write the result in terms of the new basis vectors in $P_3$